# present simple or would?

Tags: present-tense, would

This sentence comes from *Active Skills for Reading 3*:

> In most parts of the world, storm clouds would be greeted with a frown. But in India, it's said that when the monsoon rains come, a billion people smile.

Why has the writer used **would** and not **present simple** (i.e., are greeted)?
Grammar books say we use present simple for general statements. Why isn't the present simple used here then?

Comment: You need to include the sentence after this. *"In most parts of the world, storm clouds would be greeted with a frown. But in India, it’s said that when the monsoon rains come, a billion people smile."*

Answer (score 2):

As @Peter Shor says, we need the context of the subsequent sentence because it completes the contrast.

"would" is used in order to imply a conditional because, in some countries, storms are rare.

**Paraphrase**

"In most parts of the world, **if** storm clouds appeared, they **would** be greeted with a frown. But in India, it’s said that when the monsoon rains come, a billion people smile."

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the whole context. With the following line, it reads

> In most parts of the world, storm clouds would be greeted with a frown. But in India, it’s said that when the monsoon rains come, a billion people smile.

By using *would*, the writer is contrasting the rest of the world with India. You should interpret it as something like

> If we weren't in India, people would greet storm clouds with a frown, but in India, people greet the monsoon rains with a smile.

If the writer had used the simple present *are greeted* rather than the irrealis mood *would be greeted*, the sentence would still be grammatical and would mean essentially the same thing.